# Checkbox button not updating a selected row?

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

My selector when selected all is updating only 1 row? however if i select a row, it cannot be updated? please see my code if something's wrong, needed help.

This is the form:

```
<form action="read_message.php" method="post">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-info" name="read"><i class="icon-check"></i> Read</button>

Check All <input type="checkbox"  name="selectAll" id="checkAll" />
    <script>
    $("#checkAll").click(function () {
        $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
    </script>                   

            </div>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class="active"><a href="messages.php"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>inbox</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="sent_message_user.php"><i class="icon-envelope-alt"></i>Send messages</a></li>
            </ul>

        <?php
         $query_announcement = mysql_query("select * from message_received
                                        LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id = message_received.user_id
                                        where  message_received.receiver_id = '$session_id' order by date_sent DESC
                                        ")or die(mysql_error());
    $count_my_message = mysql_num_rows($query_announcement);    
    if ($count_my_message != '0'){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_announcement)){  
     $id = $row['message_id'];
                                     $id_2 = $row['message_id'];
                                     $fn = $row['firstname'];
                                     $ln = $row['lastname'];
     $status = $row['message_status'];
     $sender = $row['user_id'];
     $sender_name = $fn.' '.$ln;

     $receiver = $row['receiver_id'];

     ?><div class="alert alert-info">
                <div class="post"  id="del<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <div class="message_content">
                <?php echo $row['content']; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                <?php if ($status == 'read'){
                }else{ ?>
                <input id="" class="" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <?php } ?>
                </div>
                        <hr>
                Send by: <strong><?php echo  $fn.' '.$ln; ?></strong>
                <i class="icon-calendar"></i> <?php echo $row['date_sent']; ?>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <a class="btn btn-link"  href="#reply<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle="modal" ><i class="icon-reply"></i> Reply </a>
                            </div>
                        <div class="pull-right">
                        <a class="btn btn-link"  href="#<?php echo $id; ?>" data-toggle="modal" ><i class="icon-remove"></i> Remove </a>
                        <?php include("remove_inbox_message_modal.php"); ?>
                        <?php include("reply_inbox_message_modal_user.php"); ?>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>

    <?php }}else{ ?>
    <div class="alert alert-info"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> No Message Inbox</div>
    <?php } ?>      
    </form>
```

However, nevermind the isset for reply, the problem is the first function for isset read, what's wrong with the query? this is the function for the selector, read_message.php,

```
<?php include('connect.php'); ?>
<?php
include('session.php');

if (isset($_POST['read'])){
$id=$_POST['selector'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)

{
$result = mysql_query("update message_received set message_status = 'read' where message_id='$id[$i]'");
}
echo "<script> alert('Successfully Updated') </script>";
                            echo "   <script>location.replace('messages.php')</script>";    
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['reply'])){
$sender = $_POST['sender'];
$receiver = $_POST['receiver'];
$id2=$_POST['id2'];
$qwe = $_POST['qwe'];
mysql_query("update message_received set message_status = 'read' where     message_id='$id2'");

mysql_query("insert into message_received (user_id,receiver_id,content,date_sent) values('$receiver','$sender','$qwe',NOW())")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("insert into message_sent (receiver_id,user_id,content,date_sent)  values('$sender','$receiver','$qwe',NOW())")or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<script> alert('Your message has been sent') </script>";
                            echo "   <script>location.replace('messages.php')</script>";    
?>
<script>
alert('Message Sent');
window.location ="messages.php";
</script>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: and exactly how are you submitting yoru form? you have no submit buttons, and your `href="#$id">` are rather pointless, since hashes are NOT sent to the server.

Comment: I am submitting by this code, <button class="btn btn-info" name="read"><i class="icon-check"></i> Read</button>, then for the function <?php include('connect.php'); ?>
<?php
include('session.php');

if (isset($_POST['read'])){
$id=$_POST['selector'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)

{
$result = mysql_query("update message_received set message_status = 'read' where message_id='$id[$i]'");
}
echo "<script> alert('Successfully Updated') </script>";
                            echo "   <script>location.replace('messages.php')</script>";    
}
?>, my problem is the selector